# NSToolbarItem Selection Does Not Cover Text

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nstoolbar

I have an app with a standard `NSWindow` that contains a `NSToolbar` with a few `NSToolbarItem`s to act as a preference items. The `NSToolbarItem`s are set as selectable, and use the included "Template" as part of their name to get the nice system gradient effect.

However, when the `NSToolbarItem` is selected, the selection does not change the background of the text.

Each `NSToolbarItem` is marked as selectable, and my `NSToolbarDelegate` implements these two methods only:

```
-(NSArray *)toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar{
    NSMutableSet *toolbarSet = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSDictionary *prefItem in _preferenceItems){
        [toolbarSet addObject:[prefItem objectForKey:@"toolbarIdentifier"]];
    }
    return [toolbarSet allObjects];
}

-(NSArray *)toolbarSelectableItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar{
    NSMutableSet *selectableSet = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSDictionary *prefItem in _preferenceItems){
        [selectableSet addObject:[prefItem objectForKey:@"toolbarIdentifier"]];
    }
    return [selectableSet allObjects];
}
```

Here's what I'm seeing; notice the gray box around the text:

[image: behavior]

As opposed to Safari's Preferences window:

[image: safari]

Configuration of all of my `NSToolbarItem`s in Interface Builder:

[image: ib]

And the `NSToolbar` itself:

[image: toolbar]

Comment: Hmm looks like a bug to me. Did you file it with Radar?

Comment: You could try registering for notifications when a toolbar item changes, and manually sending `-setNeedsDisplay:` to the view of the selected toolbar item.

Comment: Could you provide a link for the icon(s)? Is the Icon a PNG or a PDF file?

Comment: Here's one of the images being used, directly from my "Images.xcassets" folder: http://cl.ly/image/3A3p2v0G113f/ToolsTemplate.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a part of the setup of my NSToolbarDelegate / NSWindowController I set:

```
[[[self window] contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];
```

Commenting this line out resolved the issue.

In Context:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
     NSDictionary *zendeskItem = @{@"name" : @"Zendesk Accounts",
                                  @"toolbarIdentifier" : @"zendesk"};
     NSDictionary *toolItem = @{@"name" : @"Tools",
                                  @"toolbarIdentifier" : @"tools"};
     NSDictionary *supportItem = @{@"name" : @"Support",
                                  @"toolbarIdentifier" : @"support"};
     NSDictionary *healthItem = @{@"name" : @"Health",
                                  @"toolbarIdentifier" : @"health"};
     NSDictionary *aboutItem = @{@"name" : @"About",
                                 @"toolbarIdentifier" : @"about"};

     _preferenceItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:zendeskItem, toolItem, supportItem, healthItem, aboutItem, nil];

    [[self window] setContentSize:[_zendeskView frame].size];
    [[[self window] contentView] addSubview:_zendeskView];
    //[[[self window] contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];

    currentViewTag = 1;
}
```